# Integrate nodsjs as embedded website in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, node.js, wordpress

I need some help.

I'm kind of new to javascript, but I built a flight search single page application using nodejs and angularjs and the Skyscanner API.

Now I would like to integrate this application as an embedded website in a wordpress in order to enjoy the advantages of wordpress. Does anybody have experience with this? Do the two system compete? Whats the best way to do this?

As wordpress is based on php, I guess there should be some troubles, maybe you know a turnaround.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an iframe in order to embed a page that you're running in your Node.js environment or just provide some APIs from your Node.js server and call them from WordPress the way you prefer (jQuery, Angular.js or whatever). I don't see any particular issue about running an Angular app in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress itself is written in PHP but whatever frontend you build with it can access your API written in Node, either directly from Angular or indirectly via PHP.

If you can get your Angular app embedded in WordPress then you shouldn't have problems accessing your Node API from it (keep in mind that you may need to configure CORS correctly).

But whether you can get your Angular app embedded in WordPress may be a big "if".